# Creating and populating elements for each object in array, with respective object data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dom, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a list of values from a sorted array that will automatically generate a DOM element for each unique object inside of the sorted array.

I have a JSFiddle here since it requires DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/o09aenby/1/

Array of objects is generated with

```js
// random value for the sake of unique objects
let randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  
  const data = {
    value: randomVal
    }
  
  array.push(data);
  let sortedValues = (array) => {
    return array.sort((a, b) => {
        return b.value - a.value;
    })
  }
  
  sortedArray = sortedValues(array);
```

I loop through the sorted array and create a DOM element with this for loop

```js
let displayData = [];
displayData = sortedArray;

for (let i = 0; i < displayData.length; i++) {
    let element = document.createElement('p');
    element.classList.add('data-output', 'node');
    element.innerHTML = `Value: ${data.value}`
    list.append(element);
  }
```

The goal is to keep the array of data because I will be saving it to a localStorage JSON and populating based off of the JSON later, so the data of the array needs to be preserved.

I have tried using forEach but also couldn't manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update `data` here:

```
element.innerHTML = `Value: ${data.value}`
```

so you are setting every element to the same value.  You need to do

```
element.innerHTML = `Value: ${displayData[i].value}`
```